# JComboBox is a raw type. References to generic type JComboBox<E> should be parameterized

Tags: java, generics, parameterized, type-safety

```
String[] boxOptions = {"1","2","4","8","16","20","40","100","400"};
JComboBox box = new JComboBox(boxOptions);
```

I had these exact lines of code in my program before, and wasn't getting this error. I did a bit of searching and the results I found are going a bit over my head. Any ideas?

The error is:

```
JComboBox is a raw type. References to generic type JComboBox<E> should be parameterized
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use:

```
JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(boxOptions);
```

This happens because `JComboBox` is now a generic class.

Answer (score 7):

As of Java 7, generics were introduced into JComboBox component. Maybe you were using Java6 before.
You should add `JComboBox<String>` to the second line there.

Comment: Strange. It looks like one of the projects was using JRE7 and one is using JavaSE-1.7...